# Приложение с Microsoft sync framework распространение

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет!

У меня есть программа, использующая MS sync framework.
Как можно использовать мою программу, не устанавливая sync framework.
Может есть какие-нибудь пути обхода (скопировать нужные dll и т.п.?).
Ваши советы? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем, чтобы всё заработало как надо нужно скопировать все dll из \sync framework\2.1\runtime, положить их с ехе, сделать regsvr32 для всех dll с 21 на конце.

Вроде так вот зафунциклировало!

Answer (score 1):

Sync Framework работает через COM, а значит в принципе требует как минимум прав администратора для установки. Если права администратора есть, и нужно просто избежать самого запуска инсталлера, то должно хватить просто регистрации соответствующих COM-объектов перед первым запуском приложения:

```
regsvr32 /s synchronization21.dll
```

и, естественно, копирования всех dll, на которые вы ссылаетесь из приложения.

Официально этот путь не поддерживается, и, судя по [этому запросу в connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/671755/please-make-sync-framework-com-independent) вообще является нарушением лиценионного соглашения.

Comment: Спасибо! А как определить нужные DLL,на которые ссылается приложение (в референсах которые прописаны Microsoft.synchronization и Microsoft.synchronization.files)? И куда класть эти DLL? Рядом с exe-шником?

Comment: @Dmitry скопируйте все из папки установки Sync Framework, потом удаляйте по одной. и обязательно оставьте те, на которые у вас явно есть референс из приложения.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Завтра буду пробовать!

Comment: Только можно сразу всё не копировать, а просто отметить референсы, на которые ссылкается проект, на копирование при компиляции. Дополнительно см. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @SanSYS Он не все нужные dll копирует!